# Assign columname (month) as value to another column SAS

Tags: sas

Please help friends

```
data have;
input v_202002 $1. v_202003 $1. v_202001 $1.;
datalines;
a . b
. . b
a b b
. b a
b b a
;
```

What I am looking for - First time the value became 'b'

want dataset:

```
v_202002   v_202003   v_202001   output
a          .          b          202001
.          .          b          202001
a          b          b          202001
.          b          a          202003
b          b          a          202002
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WHICHC() function to find the index into an array where the value appears. Then use the VNAME() function to get the name.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array vlist v: ;
  index=whichc('b',of vlist[*]);
  if index then output = substr(vname(vlist[index]),3);
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    v_202002    v_202003    v_202001    index    output

 1        a                       b          3      202001
 2                                b          3      202001
 3        a           b           b          2      202003
 4                    b           a          2      202003
 5        b           b           a          1      202002
```

Comment: Thank you so much, whichc function supercharged my program :)